# PanGesture and some basic math

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'd like to calculate a percentage from 0-100 based on where the user "pans" the screen. If it's at the most bottom, 0%. If it's at the most top, 100%. I need this for an opacity sliding feature. A user can change the opacity of the screen by sliding, where the bottom most sets the screen to invisible while the top most sets it to brightest, 100%.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Translation: %f", translation.x);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm looking at converting `translation.x` to a percetange but it's confusing.

Comment: For vertical use `y`, not `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your view covers the entire screen, I believe the percentage you're looking for is

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGFloat percentage = 1.0 - (location.y / self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

`locationInView` gives you a point in the coordinate system of the view, which is defined by its `bounds` with (0,0) at the top left. You want the top to be 100%, hence the subtraction from 1 to flip it around (otherwise you'd get 100% at the bottom).

Comment: Not sure this is correct, im getting a 1.0 value both at the top of the screen and the bottom.

Comment: What is the value of `translation.y` in each case? What is the value of `self.view.bounds.size.height`? Also I noticed I'm using "y" in my code because you talked about "bottom" and "top". If you are actually panning left and right (hence the reference to "x" in your code) then you should use `translation.x / self.view.bounds.size.width` instead.

Comment: Middle of the screen: Translation: -100.666656 --- bottom of the screen: Translation: -2.333344 --- top of the screen Translation: 2.333344 .. id like middle to be .5 (or 50%) top to be 100% or (1) and bottom to be 0% or (0)

Comment: Sorry... just figured out what I was missing. `translationInView` gives you the relative distance that you've panned from where you started. Wherever you start is called (0,0) and all `translationInView` points after that are relative to that position. I believe what you want instead is `locationInView` which gives you the coordinates of the point in the coordinate system of the view regardless of where you started. Assuming the view in `self.view` covers the entire screen, my original code works. I'm going to go edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[translation:in:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621207-translation) give you the cumulative movement since the beginning location of the touch.  It sounds like what you are after is the touch location relative to the view's bounds and for that you should use [location:in:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location) instead.  this value .y divied by view.bounds.size.height will give you the relative distance down the screen with 0 at the top and 1 at the bottom,